# 'Oops this isn't a link to a valid profile'

Tags: support

I'm trying to delete my account on one of the Stack Exchange sites so I went to the contact form but I'm unable to provide a proper profile.

For example, https://english.stackexchange.com/users/42988/clara-onager isn't valid, so what needs to be entered into the 'your profile link' box?

Comment: Your profile on any Q&A site is what's needed. That is, the link to the profile **on the site** that you wish to be deleted.

Comment: Your profile link is auto populated. Why change it??

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the screen when you get that error?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It isn't autopopulated correctly if you log in to met stack exchange in order to do it

Comment: Not sure I follow. I just went to the "contact us" on english.stackexchange.com, chose "I need to delete my account" under "What can we help you with?" and the textbox under "Your profile link" was auto populated with my correct profile link. What exactly happens in your case? Are you logged in into http://english.stackexchange.com/ at all?

Comment: If you try to do that when not logged in, the pop up clearly says "You must be signed in to send a deletion request. Please log in and try again" - did you read it? It makes sense, otherwise users could ask to delete any other user accounts and cause total havoc. Not a good thing at all.

Comment: One final note, the profile link must point to your profile **on the same site as the "contact us" page**, e.g. you can't ask to delete your Stack Overflow account from the "contact us" of the English site or vice versa.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm sure Nicael will be happy to try to delete your account...

Comment: @rene hey don't get ideas into his head! He'll be out in the open within... 13 days... :-P

Comment: I voted to close as "Unclear what you're asking" because OP did not provide any details and failed to respond to comments.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Some people are in different time zones, they are unlikely to reply while asleep. Give them time.

Comment: @ClaraOnager I asked you several important questions **three minutes** after you replied to me. And you still did not answer even one. I honestly don't understand why you don't want to help us find the real reason you got that message.

Comment: @ClaraOnager "Some people are in different time zones, give them chance to reply", well yes, but why post that comment instead of providing the required info? You were seen then on June 2, and last seen 2 hours ago June 8, but still not provided more info. We're happy to help, but we need more specifics of what you need help with :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a link to the profile page on the site that you wish the account to be deleted on.

For the delete to be recognized as a valid request, you need to be logged in to the site you want to delete the user on and use the contact form on that site.

Trying to delete a user on a different site will fail (each site checks for local users only).

Trying to delete someone else account will fail.

---

The reasons we require being logged in and on the same site are security measures (ensuring that the delete request originates from the person who owns, that is logged into, the account).

Comment: sorry I was using that as an example, didn't realise it was special, please see edited question

Comment: One thing baffles me. If the deletion request requires one to be logged in, why require the user to give profile link? It's an unneeded step that just cause confusion, as far as I can see. Can't you just attach the link in the email sent by the system?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's mostly a hold-over from the olden days when self-served deletion didn't exist.

Comment: @Anna so if someone will start a feature request asking to remove it, will it have a chance to be done? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Every feature request has a chance to be done... But sometimes it's an infinitely small chance. ;)

Comment: @oded It was the 'use the contact form on that site' point that I hadn't realised was the problem. If you go to the main SE site and search from there the link to the contact form is to the 'wrong' contact form but there's no indication other than the 'oops' error message as to what you've done wrong.

Comment: There is no contact form in http://stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Carl: Your question is crystal clear. Cannot imagine I have exactly the same issue with you when trying to merge two accounts:  Provided the url copied exactly from stackexchange, but was told the same thing: link invalid.  I believe here it is not that the url is invalid, but the instruction/design in the form to be extra confusing.

Comment: The change-request form is here https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact/submit